# Rendering object depth in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es-2.0

I want to organize depth for objects in OpenGL ES 2.0 so that I can specify one object to be in front of other object(s)(just send uniform variable). If I want to draw two lines separatelly I just specify which one is closer.

I work with Qt and its OpenGL support. When I tend to use gl_FragDepth, it gives me linking error saying that gl_FragDepth is undeclared identifier.

Also, I tried, in vertex shader, something like `gl_Position.z = depthAttr;` where depthAttr is uniform variable for the rendering object.

Can someone tell me what else can I do, or what I did wrong? Is there preferred way?

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling gl_FragDepth from fragment shader? not vertex?

Comment: Yes I am calling it from fragment

Comment: Actually, objects should send their depth as an attribute because depth isn't the same for all objects. Why won't you send your position to the shader as vec3(x, y, z)?

Answer (score 0):

The pre-defined fragment shader output variable `gl_FragDepth` is not supported in ES 2.0. It is only available in full OpenGL, and in ES 3.0 or later.

If you really want to specify the depth with a uniform variable, you need to have the uniform variable in the vertex shader, and use it to calculate `gl_Position`. This approach from your question looks fine:

```
uniform float depthAttr;
...
gl_Position = ...;
gl_Position.z = depthAttr;
```

A much more standard approach is to make the desired depth part of your position coordinates. If you currently use 2D coordinates for drawing your lines, simply add the desired depth as a third coordinate, and change the position attribute in the vertex shader from `vec2` to `vec3`. The depth will then arrive in the shader as part of the attribute, and there's no need for additional uniform variables.

Comment: I am using third z coordinate for something else. I tried gl_Position.z = depthAttr; but the result is the same, no matter what depthAttr is.

Comment: Might be a problem with the way you set your uniform variable then. It will definitely work if the uniform variable has the correct value.

Comment: And you have a depth buffer? Depth test enabled?

Comment: I have these:  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   
    glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES 2.0 supports an optional extension - `EXT_frag_depth`, which allows the fragment shader to assign `gl_FragDepthEXT`.

See the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_frag_depth.txt), but of course, be prepared to fall back when it's not available.